# How to process amount for my app referrals?

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, referrals

I have developed an android app using flutter and I like to use stripe as my payment gateway.

I need to add refer and earn feature in my app. How do I need to setup this with my bank account for providing money one who refers.

I need to provide money like below example.

Example: If A refers B I need to give some referal money for A and If B refers C i need to give money for B and also some referal money for A(referral money for A nd B vary).

If this is not possible in stripe. which payment gateway provides this future ? or How to i do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your account as a platform and your users as connected account and you will be able to deduct from their accont and add to the other (receiver) user account.

Any charges goes to your account, and then you can distribute the money to users as you set it up in your platform account. That is one option, the second one is to do everything in your app admin section (calculate the amount to be paid) and create a charge according to your needs.

Read up on that in their doc https://stripe.com/docs/connect/best-practices